# Creating resource groups from Azure Web App Managed Service Identity

Tags: c#, azure, azure-management-api, azure-managed-identity

I'm trying to build a Bot using MS Bot framework and this bot is hosted as an Azure Web App. I've added code to create resource groups using the [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent/) APIs

```
AzureCredentialsFactory f = new AzureCredentialsFactory();
var msi = new MSILoginInformation(MSIResourceType.AppService);

var msiCred = f.FromMSI(msi, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

var azureAuth = Azure.Configure()
                 .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.BodyAndHeaders)
                 .Authenticate(msiCred);

var azure = azureAuth.WithSubscription(subscription);

var resourceGroup = azure.ResourceGroups.Define(rg)
                                    .WithRegion(Region.EuropeWest)
                                    .Create();
```

This code is levering the Managed Service Identity of the Web app. I've made this web app "Owner" of the Azure subscription.

when i execute this code i keep getting this exception

> Exception: The access token has been obtained from wrong audience or resource ’https://management.core.windows.net'. It should exactly match (including forward slash) with one of the allowed audiences ‘https://management.core.windows.net/’,’https://management.azure.com/’.

I never set the audience or resource by hand and don't see any option on how to do this.

When i change my code to use a service principal i created myself it works great

```
ServicePrincipalLoginInformation loginInfo = new ServicePrincipalLoginInformation() 
{ 
    ClientId = _clientId, 
    ClientSecret = _clientSecret 
}; 

var credentials = new AzureCredentials(loginInfo, _tenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
var azureAuth = Azure.Configure()
             .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.BodyAndHeaders)
             .Authenticate(credentials);
```

How to set this audience or resource or what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to set this audience or resource or what am i doing wrong?

I also can reproduce this issue on my side. It seems it is the SDK issue. You could report it to the [Azure SDK github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues).

**Update:**

According to [issue-4090](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/4090), it has been fixed in version 1.7, you could test again if it is released.

Comment: I will add an issue on github tnx.

Comment: Issue added here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/4090

Comment: @if it is useful, you could mark it as an answer that will more communities who have the same issue.

Comment: It is fixed in 1.7 (which is not released yet) so we'll wait and see.